# Adding background image to a Javascript "Pong" game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, open-source, pong

As part of my studies i'm modifying some parts in an open-sourced "Pong" game I found online (created by [Kushagra Agarwal](http://cssdeck.com/user/kushsolitary)).

**[Game's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLKFC/1/)**

I'm trying to set a nice background image to the game, 
that will not disturb the gameplay experience.
I've tried many ways but so far Iv'e only managed to change the background color into a different color, but not to an actual image :

```
// Function to paint canvas
function paintCanvas() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue/black/whatever";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
```

Trying to work out `ctx.fillStyle` to display an image didn't went well since `paintCanvas()` is constantly looping, and if gets other value then a "color" string (for example a background image that weighs 500kb) it will create huge delays in the game.

Anyone has an idea?

Thank's,
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks nice if your just put a background image on the body tag!

```
<body background="someImage">
</body>
```

I commented out your paintCanvas(), inserted a clear, and inserted a body tag!

http://jsfiddle.net/XLKFC/11/

```
// Function to paint canvas
function paintCanvas() {
    canvas.width = canvas.width; // Will clear the canvas
    //ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry my friend. I forgot to clear the screen in paintCanvas(). Updated answer!